# Connect to EPP Server with PHP, using SSL

Tags: php, ssl

I'm about to connect to a secure EPP server and send an XML request and then receive a response in XML format again.

I need to do this in PHP. So I need to connect to the EPP server on a specific port over TCP, using SSL Certificate (as this is the information I have so far, still waiting to whitelist my IP and send me the certificate).

So my question might seem a little dumb, but do I need to use `fsockopen` or `cURL` to connect, how do I define that I need to use SSL and how do I define and use this SSL certificate along with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you just init curl, set options and exec curl request:

```
$url="your_url";
$handle = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $sslcertpath); //$sslcertpath - path to your certificate file
curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); //may want to set false for debugging
//[...]
$response = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);

var_dump($response);
```

You can find a complete list of curl options in the manual:
[curl_setopt manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: Thanks, @Snifff. Just one follow-up question, as I need to connect on a specific port (700), I just specify this with curl_setopt as well, right?

Comment: Yes, use CURLOPT_PORT, like curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PORT, 700); But you may also just state it in your url, either in curl_init or in CURLOPT_URL.

Answer (score 0):

curl with something like

```
CURLOPT_CAINFO=>YOUR_CAINFO_PATH,
CURLOPT_SSLCERT=>YOUR_CERT_PATH,
CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD=>YOUR_CERT_PWD_IF_NECESSARY,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>1,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=>YOUR_HTTPS_TIMEOUT,
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a shot. Appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$epp_server = 'ote-console.centralnic.com'; $port = 700; $verify_peer = 0;
//$epp_server = 'epp.ispapi.net'; $port = 1700; $verify_peer = 0;
//$epp_server = 'epp.test.norid.no'; $port = 700; $verify_peer = 0;
//$epp_server = 'epp-test.rotld.ro'; $port = 5555; $verify_peer = 0; // SSLv3
$opts = array(
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => $verify_peer,
    'cafile' => "/CAfiles/gd_bundle.crt",
    'local_cert' => "/certs/certificate.cer",
    'passphrase' => 'YourCertificatePasswordHere'
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// TLSv1

$fp = stream_socket_client( "tls://$epp_server:$port", $errno, $errstr, 1, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);

// SSLv3
//$fp = stream_socket_client( "sslv3://$epp_server:$port", $errno, $errstr, 1, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);

if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
}

else {
    fwrite($fp, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 1024);
    }

    fclose($fp);

}

?>
```

Comment: Since EPP is not HTTP, sending an HTTP formatted message inside an EPP connection will certainly not work...